# Pointers: "Expected identifier before '(' token"

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

**Project:** Source to Destination Fare Matrix

**Language:** C.

**Rationale:** This is for a school exercise. My output is past a day's due and all the problem is this one kind of line of code that I have no clue what the problem is about.

**Objective:** To make a program that gets source node, destination node and cost values respectively from a list. After processing the entire list, the program should ask the user which node he/she wishes to see. When the user inputs the node number, the program should output a list of the node's possible destinations and their respective costs. The program should use as MINIMAL memory as possible (hence the use of pointers over arrays).

**Scope:** Pointers and Structures.

**Problem in code:**
*These are the variables*

```
int nodes, edges, src, dst, cst, loop=0, temp=0;
```

Nodes are for the number of different nodes. Edges are for the number of connections. Src is for the number of the source node, dst for the number of the destination node and cst for their corresponding cost. Loop is a counter for the number of time the program will scan the file. Temp is a value holder to make the code easier to read.

*This is the structure*

```
typedef struct path {
    int num;
    int *cost;
    int *neighbors;
}path;
```

*This is the area of the problem*

```
fscanf (file, "%d %d", &nodes, &edges);
```

This gets the number of nodes and connections from the fist line in the file.

```
printf("%d %d\n", nodes, edges);
path list[25000]={[0 ... 24999]{.num=0}};
```

Normally, I shouldn't be doing this. The size should be dependent on the number of nodes at the beginning of the file but I thought the problem stemmed from list not being an array. This is actually a compromise on the "Minimal Memory" part. If someone can improve this, I'd be very much obliged.

```
path * listp;
listp=&list;
puts("Processing data...");
while (loop<edges)
{
   fscanf (file, "%d %d %d", &src, &dst, &cst);
```

This is what gets the values from the file list.
       (listp+src)->num++;
       (listp+dst)->num++;
This is to increase the number of connections on both the source and destination node every time I encounter their numbers on the list.

```
realloc((listp+src)->cost, (listp+src)->num);
realloc((listp+src)->neighbors, (listp+src)->num);
```

This is to increase the amount of memory available at cost and neighbor so I can store more values. I'm not encountering any errors here but I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. Please inform me if I'm not.

```
temp=((listp+src)->num)-1;
```

This is to make the code more palpable.

```
(listp+src)->(cost+temp)=&cst;
(listp+src)->(neighbors+temp)=&dst;
```

**THIS.** This here is where the "Expected identifier before '(' token" errors come up. I really have no clue on what I'm doing wrong here. Please help me :(

```
realloc((listp+dst)->cost, (listp+dst)->num);
realloc((listp+dst)->neighbors, (listp+dst)->num);
temp=((listp+dst)->num)-1;
(listp+dst)->(cost+temp)=&cst;
(listp+dst)->(neighbors+temp)=&src;
loop++;
}
```

Basically a rinse and repeat for the destination node.

So my only problem is the one emphasized on top. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I think there might be other errors with my code as well, but so far the compiler hasn't warned me of them. If anyone notices any other possible errors, it would be a big help to me if they could point it out as well. Please and thank you.

Comment: `(listp+dst)->(neighbors+temp)` What is this even supposed to mean? `listp[dst]->neighbors[temp]`?

Comment: Since listp is a pointer structure, you have to dereference listp before calling a variable inside the structure. '->' is a shortcut for calling listp.neighbors without having to dereference listp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(listp+dst)->(cost+temp)` is syntactically invalid: the compiler is trying to tell you it expects an identifier that would be a pointer on function, so that `(listp+dst)->foo(cost+temp)` becomes a well-formed expression.

You should thus, if I understood correctly what you try to do, use `(*listp)[dst].cost[temp]`. Or, if you really prefer pointer arithmetics, `((listp+dst)->cost+tmp)`, noting the change in parenthesizing.